# Typing 'à' on LaTeX

Tags: accents, characters

I would like to know how to type the letter 'à' in LaTeX. There is no grave accent on my Italian keyboard, so everytime I need that letter I just copy and paste a grave accent from the list of symbols on my computer. The sequence \`a gives the right result. Clearly I would like to find a more comfortable way to do this job.

I have seen the command `\char'140` gives a grave accent, but I do not know how to put this control sequence together with backslash and a. E.g. I cannot write `\\char'140a`. Should I define a macro? It seems like brute force to a much simpler problem. I am sorry if this is a duplicate, but I cannot find any other answer about this problem. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I don't completely understand what your aim is. You say that  `\\`a` is too cumbersome, but consider something even longer like a macro. I'd say that your question is not about TeX but about how to enter accented characters on your keyboard under your operating system. This may work with compose key sequences or making the accent a dead key. Regarding LaTeX, you just have to use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in the preamble (or maybe some encoding other than `utf8`).

Comment: This answer claims that you have an à on your keyboard (and shows some ways how to get the backtick at least on windows): https://superuser.com/questions/667622/italian-keyboard-entering-the-tilde-and-backtick-characters-without-cha

Comment: @gernot I am not saying that `\\`a` is too cumbersome. I say that I would like to avoid to go to the list of symbols everytime I need to type a grave accent. So I was wondering if there is a shorter way, maybe a particular command, to type the letter 'à' in LaTeX. Maybe you are right, this question might not be about TeX. I am just trying to find an answer here in case it is related to TeX.

Comment: Depending on the settings of your editor and/or operating system, you can either input the accented characters by typing a compose key (you have to find out which key it is or configure one), the letter and the accent, or you just have to type the accent and the letter. In both cases this will give a single character that will work with LaTeX if you tell it the encoding that your editor/operating system uses. In any case it is not possible to be more specific without knowing the details of your working environment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about configuring your editor or your keyboard and not about TeX

Comment: Doesn't your keyboard have an `à` key? So long as you save your document as UTF-8, there will be no problem in LaTeX interpreting it.

Comment: @egreg can you be more precise?

Comment: @Gibbs What's unclear? Just type `à`.

Comment: If I upload the package inputenc with utf8 and type à, LaTeX does not typeset anything, it gives me an error.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [LaTeX wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters), you could use alt codes to generate the desired characters. I found these alt codes on [Useful Shortcuts](https://usefulshortcuts.com/alt-codes/accents-alt-codes.php):

```
Alt 0192    À
Alt 0224    à
```